# Tooltips not showing when hovering over SVG polygons

Tags: html, svg, tooltip

I have an SVG map of Colorado with polygons for each county.  I'd like the county name to pop up on mouse hover, but that isn't happening.  I have the counties set to change fill on hover, too, and that **is** happening.  I'm not sure what the difference is.

These are just standard browser tooltips, with the intended text set in each polygon's `title` attribute.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmparker/sVbxT/4/

Comment: It has been too long but have you figured this out?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For SVG you need to use a nested `<title>` element rather than a title attribute. E.g. `<polygon points="..."><title>your title</title></polygon>`

Comment: What about Edge? Is it not supported?