# alt and title not showing up as tooltip for svg path

Tags: html, svg

I have some svg paths:

```
<path class="country" id="BLR" title="Belarus" alt="Belarus" d="M948.0142678672362,369.7256153651123L956.0315144997886,372.7549948212553L955.6251153181965,376.68106491420883L956.6993702966163,377.46634055469417L958.4144244330968,381.52092337306806L959.8614899624631,381.6111705103533L961.4358247718692,383.8516898475525L959.6328069741484,385.0654037682009L957.3752698953709,384.53552051711677L958.4665656000917,390.0076939606045L955.9148066459876,390.24630230981074L954.0730841220384,394.2297858860991L953.163550030379,393.0762648682822L950.333965883297,393.353478804788L943.9500919704785,392.13801133565164L939.2092506948762,390.2052953894462L934.5569856401167,390.2170281135237L931.9231336584982,391.7484512915885L932.3814647774813,388.98495674038986L931.0289993180527,387.81385807072303L933.4265401596901,386.10558265025156L933.7995387046943,384.91739193713676L933.1171566924312,379.6478010722885L935.6115604269471,380.1186619031289L939.5640872868389,378.3386011842294L940.8357423463007,375.41130363641486L942.8397126276869,373.56246283729985L943.307715755223,371.87935555833474L946.3215777553021,371.35369709054953Z"></path>
```

I have both title and alt for each path. When I mouse over the paths in Firefox, I get the little tooltip with the country name. But when I do that in IE or Chrome, nothing happens. Does anyone know why, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tooltips not showing when hovering over SVG polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222345/tooltips-not-showing-when-hovering-over-svg-polygons)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Apparently, the correct way to do this in Chrome is to add a `<title>` element as a child element. See [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/CX8WmowIFa4) for more details about this issue.

So it should look like:

```
<path>
    <title>Belarus</title>
</path>
```

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxy/14/)

Comment: Extra info @Niloct: you can add a `<title>` element at any stage in the SVG hierarchy (e.g., inside a `<g>` element or nested `<svg>`) and it should apply for the parent element and any other children.  However, if the `<title>` is a child of the root SVG it will act like an HTML title (i.e., be displayed in your browser title-bar) *if* the SVG is a stand-alone file.  If the <svg> is inline in an HTML file, you don't get a tooltip for a top-level title, but screen readers will still see it. http://jsfiddle.net/xXGmu/  P.S.  The `<desc>` element is similar, but for longer descriptions/alt text.

Comment: @LauraNMS I assume you mean icanc's original fiddle, which used d3 (mine just had hard-coded SVG!).  Either way, glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: What about Edge? I see it's not fully compatible for tooltip, but is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

simple soultion :

Your solution is here:

checkout once (**practical Example** https://codepen.io/brianplaza/pen/DfKsx

> in html  :

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="959px" 
height="593px" viewBox="none" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
xml:space="preserve" >
<path id="HI" fill="#E0E0E0" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.75"
 d="M233.1,519.3l1.9-3............977.53.7l"/>
<path id="Alaska" class="enabled" fill="#21669E" stroke="#FFFFFF" 
 stroke-width="0.75" d="M158.1,453.7l-0........519.3l1"/>

</svg>

// this is important ... it will show tooltip
<div class="description"></div>
<script 
src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'>
 </script>
```

> in js

```
$description = $(".description");

  $('.enabled').hover(function() {
    
    $(this).attr("class", "enabled heyo");
    $description.addClass('active');
    $description.html($(this).attr('id'));
  }, function() {
    $description.removeClass('active');
  });

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
  
  $description.css({
    left:  e.pageX,
    top:   e.pageY - 70
  });
  
});
```

> in css

```
 .heyo:hover {
     fill: #CC2929;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.enabled {
  fill: #21669E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.description {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #21669e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #eee;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: none;
}
.description.active {
  display: block;
}
.description:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting but does not answer the original question, which was about getting the `title` attribute to show a browser tooltip. You are using javascript to physically position a floating <div> over the SVG and replacing the div's contents with the `id` of the SVG element (better to use another attribute like `data-title` in my opinion).  By using child `<title>` nodes as in Tejen's answer, the browser does all the work of positioning and showing the tooltip.