# Custom path title for SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently working on a svg and I was wondering if it was possible to easily pop a tooltip while hovering some elements.

I discovered that the attribute title is available while used like this :

```
<path>
    <title>Custom title</title>
</path>
```

I then thought about customizing the title element, so that it might spawn quicker, with a different background etc ...

So I tried different things like :

```
path[title]:hover:after { instructions }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Does someone knows an easy way to customize title from path elements ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Second edit (ARRGGHH!):

The website: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip shows how to do styling of tooltips like you wanted.

EDIT:

For SVG tooltips for a path, it is like this:

```
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z">
     <title>This is a traingle</title>
  </path>
```

Hope this works and it does because I tested it.

===========

If you want a tooltip on an image element do this:

```
<img title="tooltip text"></img>
```

It is the same for other things too.

Also, when you put brackets in the css, that is to put:

```
path[attribute=value]
```

So you would want:

```
path title:hover:after { 
  // styling 
}
```

I am glad to help. Hope this works!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help!
The problem is that it doesn't work for path from svg
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867178/alt-and-title-not-showing-up-as-tooltip-for-svg-path

Comment: Okay, now I did some research and I understand. The article that I came across was the article you just said which didn't make sense but now I do because I know a little about SVG's now. Yes it should work. Can I see your code. You can post the whole SVG code in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Cephou Okay so read the answer again because I edited it to make it work. I tested it. You just had a blank path. It will work now.

Comment: Does it work with a custom css ?
Because you can create a title for a path element but then it seems that customizing the title isn't supported :(

Comment: I figured how to apply a title to a path element. My original question was to figure how to customize a title from a path element.

Comment: For the title, no you can't. Tooltips can't be styled because it is a OS feature, not a webpage feature.

Comment: Alright, I'll find another way to make it then :)
Thank you for you answers :)

Comment: Wait, http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip is a good way to do that. Just put those styles in and set the path to have the class of tooltip. Have another child element with the tooltip class and the class of tooltiptext. Don't use the title element. That is how you do it! YEAAAHHH!!!