# Show text on hover on polygon in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

**Is that possible to add text on hover with svg polygon shape?**

**My code like this**

```html
    <svg>
    <polygon class="st0" points="0,1.833 638,1.833 383,348.833 0,348.833 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="0,355.333 649,355.333 891.5,664.833 0,664.833 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="392.5,348.833 514.75,181.333 645.25,348.833 "/>
    <polyline class="st0" points="518.875,174.908 644.667,2.021 1139.833,1.52 1139.75,663.583 897.25,663.583 "/>
    </svg>
```

when I checked many reference there is only examples for a single polygon, But on my code I need 4 shape with different text in a SVG tag. Is that possible to add text on hover with multiple polygons?

[Here a fiddle what I have](https://jsfiddle.net/coder_303/2hgo8or1/8/)

When I hover I want like this
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: What kind of "text"? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D text on hover. its clear! read question Header

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yo can add

```
<title>Your text</title>
```

tag inside `<svg></svg>` or `<poligon></poligon>` tag that shows default tooltip with text on it.

Updated [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2hgo8or1/9/)

**Source:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title
- [Tooltips not showing when hovering over SVG polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222345/tooltips-not-showing-when-hovering-over-svg-polygons)

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #0491B7;
}
.st1 {
  fill: #0491B7;
}
.st1:hover {
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.st0:hover {
  fill: red;
}

text{
  display:none;
  fill:#fff;
  font-size:2em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

text.sub-text{
  display:none;
  fill:#fff;
  font-size:0.8em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

g:hover > text{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1139.833px" height="663.313px" viewBox="0 0 1139.833 663.313" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1139.833 663.313;" xml:space="preserve">
 
  <g>
  <polygon class="st0" points="0,0.313 638,0.313 383,347.313 0,347.313 ">
    <title>One</title>
  </polygon>
  <text x="10" y="40"> TITLE </text>
    <text x="10" y="55" class="sub-text">Some Content</text>
    </g>

  <polygon class="st1" points="0,353.813 649,353.813 891.5,663.313 0,663.313 ">
    <title>Two</title>
  </polygon>

  <polygon class="st0" points="392.5,347.313 514.75,179.813 645.25,347.313 ">
    <title>Three</title>
  </polygon>

  <polyline class="st0" points="518.875,173.388 644.667,0.501 1139.833,0 1139.75,662.063 897.25,662.063">
    <title>Four</title>
  </polyline>
</svg>
```

Comment: ya, it rocks.. Thanks @eirenaios